# Are there tools to help me answer questions on multiple Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm registered on about 30 Stack Exchange websites. I think I could answer the occasional question on at least half of them. However I never do, because I need to remember to visit each and every one. Instead, when I feel like answering some questions, I only browse through the questions on Stack Overflow.

Is there any way to aggregate questions from all the sites I'm registered on, filtering by interesting tags on each one, and seeing them all in one big list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you go to your [network account page](https://stackexchange.com/users/15581), you will notice that there is a "tagged questions" tab.

> [image: screenshot]

By default that page shows you two list of questions: "My Sites" and "Favorite Tags." The first list all the questions asked in the sites where you have an account, and the second list all the questions tagged with your favorite tags, asked in any Stack Exchange site where you have an account. If you are interested in other questions, or you want a list that include less questions, you can create a new filter. In the screenshot below, I have already created two filters.

> [image: screenshot]

If you click on "New filter," you will get a new page where you can set the criteria for the questions to be included in the filtered list.

> [image: screenshot]
>
> [image: screenshot]

You can add more than one rule, as I did with my filter.

> [image: screenshot]

Once you created a filter, you have also a RSS feed for that filter. The icon is visible in the bottom right side of the filter page.

> [image: screenshot]

#### Update

The link has been changed to *Filtered Questions*. For the rest, what I said is still valid.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: By the way, did you use a screenshot program like Jing or SnagIt, or just edited in an image editor? I'm on Jing and looking for a decent replacement.

Comment: I use [Skitch Plus](http://skitch.com/) on a Mac.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the [network tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/), which sends you scheduled emails about new questions posted to your desired email address.

[image]

If you don't want to receive emails, there's a RSS feed available with the filter you created and you can subscribe to the RSS feed using a RSS feed reader like [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com) or [NewsBlur](http://newsblur.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an RSS aggregator/reader with the tag RSS feature (hover over a tag and see the subscribe | RSS links).

This will let you see all new questions in your RSS reader, from multiple sites.

Comment: Could you recommend one? (web based, so that I can use it from any computer)

Comment: [Google reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/).

Comment: Google Reader is dead. The heir apparent seems to be [Feedly](http://feedly.com).